# How to group on one column and sort on date and each date is sorted by hours in timeseries data using pandas

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, time-series

I am working on timeseries data and using pandas for analyzing the data. My data looks like:

[image]

The columns are "Datetime, date, time, price, a, b, c, area, y". Now I have to group this data by area which I can do by:

```
df.groupby('area')
```

Now I can sort this data on date column by:

```
df = df.sort_values(['date'])
```

But if I sort date column then the time column is automatically sorted, but I need for eg:

```
date        time     area
2018-09-13 02:00:00  5 
2018-09-13 03:00:00  5
2018-09-13 02:00:00  3
2018-09-13 03:00:00  3
```

How can I achieve this in pandas? Any suggestions! Thanks